# I want to hash my password but some fields should not be required

Tags: python, django

In django validation when I signup, i don't want to validate some fields because they are not required, but if i am creating user from another page there i want those fields, so how to do unrequired some fields

```
**Serializers.py**
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "username", "password" ,"first_name", "last_name","email", "User_Type","url","sign_up_count", "facebook", "twitter", "linkedin", "instagram", "telegram", "discord", "snapchat"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
        last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
        username=validated_data['email'],
        User_Type=validated_data['User_Type'],
        facebook=validated_data['facebook'],
        twitter=validated_data['twitter'],
        linkedin=validated_data['linkedin'],
        instagram=validated_data['instagram'],
        telegram=validated_data['telegram'],
        discord=validated_data['discord'],
        snapchat=validated_data['snapchat'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

```
**view.py**
class CreateUserByAdmin(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        data.update(username = data.get('email'))
        try:
            if User.objects.filter(email=data.get('email')).exists():
                return Response({'details' : 'User Already Exists'}, 403)
            else:
                serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
                print("serializer Data == > ", serializer.data)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()            
                    return Response({'details' : 'User Created'})
                else:
                    return Response({'details' : 'Somthing went Wrong'}, 403)
        except:
            return Response({'details' : 'Somthing went Wrong1'}, 403)
```

```
**view.py**
def post(self, request):
        params = request.query_params.get("refer")
        try:
            refer_by=User.objects.get(url=params)
            data = json.dumps(request.data)
            data = json.loads(data)
            username=AddUser(request,data)
            SendAccountVerifcationEmail(data)
            refer_by=User.objects.get(url=params)
            refer_to=User.objects.get(username=username)
            ReferLink(refer_by,refer_to)
            return Response({"ok":"ok"})

        except:
            data = json.dumps(request.data)
            data = json.loads(data)
            username=AddUser(request,data)
            SendAccountVerifcationEmail(data)
            return Response({"ok":"ok"})
```

```
**helpers.py**
def AddUser(request,data):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        username=request.data["email"]
        # user_email=request.data["email"]
        user = User.objects.get(email=username)
        user.username = username
        user.save()
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        if username:
            return username
        else:
            return "Ok"
```

when i signup a account i dont want facebook, telegram and more..., but if i am creating user from another page that time i neet it. so how to set unrequired fields for validate

Comment: Two separate serializers would do the trick

Comment: Will you please elaborate

Comment: Do you have two separate views to create sign up and creating user from another page?

Comment: Yes, I have two saprate views

Comment: But serializer is only one

Comment: You can use different serializers for same model and require different fields in them

Comment: sir I can't understanding, please help if you can

Comment: I am trying it from morning

Comment: Could you update your question to include your two views?

Comment: Yes, sir I edited the question

Comment: Check if my answer helps

Comment: Sir will you help me ? I can wait...

Comment: I posted answer, could you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have one serializer: `UserSerializer`, and this serializer requires all fields like linkedin etc.

You should leave it as it is or even rename it to WebsiteRegistrationUserSerializer to be more clear what this serializer is used to.

Next step is to declare AdminRegistrationUserSerializer like that:

```
class AdminRegistrationUserSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "username", "password" ,"first_name", "last_name","email", "User_Type", <all_fields_you_want_to_include>]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

And after that you can change serializer in `CreateUserByAdmin` to `AdminRegistrationUserSerializer`